# Is the phrase "one time setup" ambiguous?

Tags: phrases

Would the phrase "one time setup" be ambiguous to an international audience of software developers?

They have two choices: a setup procedure that has to be done at the start of every new session, or a setup procedure that is done only the first time they use the software.

Might "one time" be taken to mean the setup will only be operational one time?

If so, what are unambiguous terms to use here?

Comment: A quick poll of my colleagues agreed with me that we'd take "one time setup" to mean it was only done once at installation and not per session.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: The question's focus on language might be clearer if "task" was substituted for the technical term "setup." Super User [describes itself](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as for questions about computer hardware, software, or networking.

Comment: You are asking if **one-time** (with hypen) means many times or each time. No worries. The techies who perform that setup, once, know exactly what it means as standard language.

Answer (score 0):

"One time setup" would be clear to native English speakers so I don't want to substitute another term for it, but the name for the other setup type could make the distinction apparent. So I suggest:

- One time setup
- Single session setup

Comment: Why does "setup" have to be part of the second phrase? Couldn't you use "Session configuration" to avoid confusion?